# java Package "mylist" does not exist

Tags: java

in the main method, the line **mylist.BuildList** is giving error ***package mylist does not exist***.

Since everything is in one file, I dont understand this error.

I have removed all extra code from the program.

How do I fix this error and what is causing it.

Help is appreciated.

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*;

public class LinkedList {

//private static node head;
 node q = new node("",null);  
 node head = new node("",q); 

 public void BuildList() {

return;
 }


 public void DisplayList(node q){

      if (q != null)
      { System.out.println(q.data);
           DisplayList(q.next);}
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
      LinkedList mylist = new LinkedList();
      String oneLine = "";


while(!oneLine.equals("$done")){
   try{BufferedReader indata = new      
   // future switch statement
          mylist.BuildList();


   }catch(Exception e){ System.out.println("Error --" + e.toString());}    

     } // controlling while loop      
 }// end main  



}  // end class linked list  

class node {
     String data;
     node next;

     public node(){ 
          data="";
          next=null;
     }

     public node(String x,node n){
        data=x;
        next=n;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You started writing something after your try statement, and then stopped:

```
try{BufferedReader indata = new     // HERE
// future switch statement
      mylist.BuildList();
```

This is equivalent to:

```
try{
    BufferedReader indata = new mylist.BuildList();
```

Which interprets mylist as a package, and BuildList as a class constructor. Just make sure you complete the statement after the try, and close it with a semicolon (or just delete it, or comment it out for now):

```
try{
    //BufferedReader indata = new // TODO
    mylist.BuildList();
```